# Paste a string into another string with position

Tags: r

I'd like to paste a string "19" into another string but determining a different order place. For instance, in the following I need to paste "19" counting from the second digit backwards given a value in column b: "1101.77" to "1101.1977". How can I do that?

```
df<- structure(list(a = c("1101.77", "10990", "103250", "10.96", "9.906", "10.70", 
"11.43", "11.41", "10.48512", "11.19"), b = c(1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 
4, 0)), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've tried like this, however, "19" is pasted always at the end of the string no matter how I change start and end parameters:

```
rows <- which(df$b==1)
if(length(rows)>0){
df$a[rows] <- paste(str_sub(df$a[rows],start = 1, end = 6),'19',sep="")
}
```

Comment: that start and end are for substring, following your way, use strsub(first four) and 19 and strsub(last two) and paste

Comment: Can you paste the expect output for `df$a` b/c I'm not following what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
rows <- which(df$b==1)
if(length(rows)>0){
print(df$a[rows])
df$a[rows] <- paste(str_sub(df$a[rows],start=-7,end=-3),'19',sep="",str_sub(df$a[rows],start = -2, end = -1))
print(df$a[rows])
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the logic is to convert your object to string, then find the char "." position, after that you can insert the new string temp with your value, then convert your object to decimal again.
this code like this :

```
intori = 1101.77;
strori = cstr(intOri);
intPosPoint = indexof('.');
strtmp = left(strori,intPosPoint-1);
strtmp = strtmp &".19" & right(strori,2);
decVal = cdec(strtmp);
```